# how can restrict processes in parallel

Tags: python-3.x

I have this script, but I only want to start 3 perl processes at a time. Once these 3 are done, the script should start the next three.

at the moment all processes are started in parallel

unfortunately I don't know what to do. can someone help me?

my script:

```
import json, os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

list = open('list.txt', 'r')


procs = []
for dirs in list:
    args = ['perl', 'test.pl', '-a', dirs]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
   proc.wait()
```

list.txt :

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5
dir6
dir7
dir8
dir9
dir10
dir11
```

test.pl

```
$com=$ARGV[0];
$dirs=$ARGV[1];
print "$com $dirs";
sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module - it has the figure of a 'Process Pool' that will automatically keep only that many worker process, and start new tasks as the older ones are completed.

As target function, put a simple Python function to open your external process, and wait synchronously for the result -  a function with the lines currently inside your `for` loop.

Using concurrent.futures, your code might look like this:

```py
import json, os
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

mylist = open('list.txt', 'r')

def worker(dirs):
    args = ['perl', 'test.pl', '-a']
    proc = subprocess.run(args + [dirs])


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)  # 3 is: max-workers.
# ProcessPoolExecutor could be an option, but you don't need
# it - the `perl` process will run in other process anyway.

procs = []
for dirs in mylist:

    proc = executor.submit(worker, dirs) 
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in as_completed(procs):
   try:
        result = proc.result()
   except Exception as exc:
        # handle any error that may have been raised in the worker
        pass
```

Comment: can you help me to integrate that into the script, unfortunately that exceeds my python knowledge

Comment: yes - the example is above. I did not test it, but with this example, plust the docs at the given link, I think you can get it working.

Comment: i get this error: proc = executor.submit(worker, site) subprocess.Popen(args)

Comment: sorry - that was a typo that got there as I changed the program inplace here - it is just the function call that is needed. (fixing it now)

Comment: Basically it works, but after 3 it doesn't take a break, it all go through. Sleep is not waited for. I added the perl script in the question, and output

Comment: root@test /root # date
Mi Apr 29 20:17:44 CEST 2020
root@test /root # python3 5.py
-a dir1
-a dir4
-a dir2
-a dir3
-a dir6
-a dir5
-a dir7
-a dir9
-a dir8
-a dir10
root@test /root # date-a dir11
Mi Apr 29 20:17:46 CEST 2020

Comment: check for the documentation on `subprocess.Popen` so that Python waits for each subprocess to finish 0 it has a lot of optional parameters to control execution

Comment: I checked it - use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen` - The "Popen" class there is an overengineered thing that needs one to tune exactly in what is desired. The default behavior is to run a subprocess asynchrononously (and then, the Python worker from concurrent.futures never waits for it to finsh). While `subprocess.run` defaults to wait the subprocess to finish before resuming the Python code execution